# Math aligned, equation pushed to the left

Tags: math-mode

I am using the `aligned` environment in order to represent the equations aligned, but latex is always pushing the first line a little bit more to the left, since there is no for part there, i tried to push it back by using a phantom but it is not working

[image]

```
  \begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
     D_1(0, 0) &= 0, && \phantom{for} \\
     D_1(i, 0) &= D_1(i-1, 0) - \delta, &&  \text{for}\ 1 \leq j \leq n, \\
     D_1(0, j) &= 0, &&  \text{for}\ 1 \leq j \leq m, \\
  \end{aligned}
  \end{equation*}
```

Does someone now how could i solve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: There is technically no need for `\phantom{for}` in the first equation/condition.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks. I did not notice the `\phantom{for}`.

Answer (score 6):

If you are referring to the alignment of the `D` the reason that is slightly off is that space that a `0` occupies is different than a `i` occupies. The `aligned` environment provides a right alignment for the text *before* the `&`, which is what you were seeing.

One way to solve that would be to ensure that the letters `i` and `j` are typeset as the same width as the `0` by using a `\makebox` as wide as `\widthof{0}`:

[image]

Alternatively you can use `alignedat` as shown in the MWE to achieve similar results.

### Notes:

- As per barbara beeton's suggestion the right hand side has been placed within the `\text{}` macro.
- Also removed the `\phantom{for}` as it serves no purpose, as Werner pointed out.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\MakeBox}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{0}]{$#1$}}%

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
     D_1(0, 0) &= 0,                    &&  \\
     D_1(i, 0) &= D_1(i-1, 0) - \delta, &&  \text{for  $1 \leq j \leq n$,} \\
     D_1(0, j) &= 0,                    &&  \text{for $1 \leq j \leq m$,}, \\
  \end{aligned}  
  \end{equation*}
  Alternaively
  \begin{alignat*}{3}
     D_1&(0, 0) &&= 0,                    &&  \\
     D_1&(i, 0) &&= D_1(i-1, 0) - \delta, &&  \quad \text{for  $1 \leq j \leq n$,} \\
     D_1&(0, j) &&= 0,                    &&  \quad \text{for $1 \leq j \leq m$,} \\
  \end{alignat*}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: perhaps better style in the rightmost segments: `\text{for $1 \leq n$,}`, etc.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Good suggestion. Has been incorporated into the answer.

Comment: Hm I tried this align at you proposed but are you sure this worsk always?
As soon as I use another letter for my matrices the same thing happens as I posted in the first

Comment: @user65388: The above solution is intended to work for the case given, where the spacing difference was due to the width of the `0` character being wider than `i`. So, you can update the question with a another example, or try the second solution I provided using `alignat*`.

Comment: I used alignat* since i liked that solution more :).
Well there is no "new example" to post, i just tried your solution and then mixed the matrix name, so I had a second one `H_1`

Comment: @user65388: If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: The `\MakeBox` command doesn't seem to be used anywhere... is that a typo?  or is that correct?

Comment: @AndrewSpott: Yeah, left over from an earlier solution, but is mentioned in the text.